# Pivot a JSON in Snowflake with possible CASE statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to parse the below nested JSON in snowflake so that it appears as a column. basically i want my final data to look like this. I think the approach I want to take is PIVOT and then select the min but and use a CASE when statement but I'm not too sure.

```
       Mins_FirstDoorOpened_LastDoorOpened
       2

       Mins_FirstCustomerEntered_LastCustomerEntered
       null

       Mins_FirstEmployeClockedIn_LastEmployeeClockedIn
       3
```

```
"IntervaTime": [
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstDoorOpened",
      "Goal": "2",
      "Order": "1",
      "ToActivity": "LastDoorOpened"
    },
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstCustomerEntered",
      "Order": "2",
      "ToActivity": "LastCustomerEntered"
    },
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstEmployeClockedIn",
      "Goal": "9",
      "Order": "3",
      "ToActivity": "LastEmployeClockedIn"
    }, 
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UDF for this*.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_interval(IntervaTime array, activity string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
  return INTERVATIME.filter(item => item.FromActivity == ACTIVITY).map(item => item.Order)[0];
$$
;

with tbl as (select parse_json(t.$1) mycol from values ('{"IntervaTime": [
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstDoorOpened",
      "Goal": "2",
      "Order": "1",
      "ToActivity": "LastDoorOpened"
    },
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstCustomerEntered",
      "Order": "2",
      "ToActivity": "LastCustomerEntered"
    },
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstEmployeClockedIn",
      "Goal": "9",
      "Order": "3",
      "ToActivity": "LastEmployeClockedIn"
    }
]}') t)

select
  get_interval(mycol['IntervaTime'], 'FirstDoorOpened') FirstDoorOpened,
  get_interval(mycol['IntervaTime'], 'FirstCustomerEntered') FirstCustomerEntered,
  get_interval(mycol['IntervaTime'], 'FirstEmployeClockedIn') FirstEmployeClockedIn
from tbl;
```

*I've made some assumptions, so this assume I got them correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I think you might be headed down a rabbit hole; this is not how relational data sets work (in general).

Also, is the last row's value supposed to be "9" (not "3")? You did not define where it comes from, so I assumed that it is the "Goal" attribute.

```
WITH CTE_1 AS (
  SELECT PARSE_JSON($1) AS MY_JSON
    FROM VALUES
           ($$
{
"IntervaTime": [
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstDoorOpened",
      "Goal": "2",
      "Order": "1",
      "ToActivity": "LastDoorOpened"
    },
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstCustomerEntered",
      "Order": "2",
      "ToActivity": "LastCustomerEntered"
    },
    {
      "FromActivity": "FirstEmployeClockedIn",
      "Goal": "9",
      "Order": "3",
      "ToActivity": "LastEmployeClockedIn"
    }
]
}
$$)
)
,CTE_2 AS (
SELECT X2.VALUE:"Order"::INTEGER AS EVENT_SEQ
      ,'Mins_' || X2.VALUE:"FromActivity"::VARCHAR || '_' || X2.VALUE:"ToActivity"::VARCHAR AS LINKED_EVENTS
      ,X2.VALUE:"Goal"::VARCHAR AS GOAL
      ,*
  FROM CTE_1 X
      ,LATERAL FLATTEN(TO_ARRAY(X.MY_JSON:"IntervaTime")) X2
)
,CTE_3 AS (
  SELECT EVENT_SEQ AS SORT1
        ,0 AS SORT2
        ,LINKED_EVENTS AS OUTPUT_STR
    FROM CTE_2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT EVENT_SEQ
        ,1
        ,GOAL
    FROM CTE_2
)
SELECT OUTPUT_STR
  FROM CTE_3
 ORDER BY SORT1
         ,SORT2
;
```